# Deploying Django app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk : Application url shows only " Index of / "

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ebs

I'm trying the deploy this :

https://github.com/agrawal-mohit/kudisavers

on AWS using EBS.

But the landing page show only " Index of / " : http://kudisavers.elasticbeanstalk.com/

I'm inexperienced with deployment et all and need some help on this. What is going wrong here?

Much thanks!

Comment: it seems like the app didn't deploy properly. did you check the logs on elastic beanstalk?

Comment: experiencing a similar issue. the same application works on another environment for me, but deploying a new environment does not work (just shows "index of /")

Comment: @PatrickYan : By 'another environment' , you mean?

Comment: @mystikacid An existing environment with the application works normally. Launching a new environment just shows "index of /". I found out that the new environment works after adding an SSL certificate, but AWS support team has no idea why.

Comment: any luck with this? Running into the same problem

Comment: I am having the same problem. And when I deploy a new version (to new environment or not, it doesn't matter), I get an error "update completed but with errors. Check troubleshooting for help". But I cannot download the logs and when I ssh into the instance, logs were empty.

Answer (score 1):

If landing page show only " Index of / ", your project was deployed successful, but it failed while running django app (./manage py). So try `~$ eb logs` in your project dir and find error while running your app. In my case there was default package "pkg-resources". You should remove it from `requirements.txt` .

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Django’s demo app deploys successfully but my complex app with lot of packages would always generate this error.
Do eb ssh from local terminal , it will take u into ec2 terminal. Then try installing the exact Django version from your requirements.txt file manually using pip. You would see that ec2 doesn’t have that Django version. 
That’s what is happening with few other packages too .
You can check installed packages in your ec2 by pip freeze. 
If you manually install some other version of Django on ec2  - website will work.